# Prevent deadlock SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, php-7.4, laravel-queue

I need help with preventing deadlocks. How can I update my code to prevent or minimize deadlocks?

The 'ProductAutoMapUpdater' is executed by admin and it is also executed as a background process at a specified interval.

I am getting below deadlock errors in different tables, for the job 'ProductAutoMapUpdater':

```
SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction (SQL: insert into `product_accessories` (`accessory_id`, `product_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `cross_sell`) values (54392d5a-565f-486b-b17c-4cf7e6dc53bd, 2d7c997e-7591-4e08-b12f-88ff9e3f359d, 2023-01-05 17:05:54, 2023-01-05 17:05:54, 1))

SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction (SQL: update `categories` set `from_only_product_id` = bcfe0008-4374-420a-b62e-c67b3fc56c68, `categories`.`updated_at` = 2023-01-05 17:05:47 where `id` = 368)

SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction (SQL: update `products` set `products`.`updated_at` = 2023-01-05 17:05:39 where `id` = f0cdfb07-23ad-4767-b1dd-420d5b1acff0)
```

The below Job invokes multiple auto mapper classes, all of which update products related data (products, categories, accessories, vouchers, medias,..).

**App\Jobs\ProductAutoMapUpdater** file

```
/**
 * Invokable auto mapper classes that will update the product.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $autoMappers = [
    UpdateDefaultExtendedAttributes::class,
    UpdateCrossSellAccessories::class,
    UpdatePrimaryProductCategory::class,
    UpdateSecondaryCategories::class,
    UpdateRelatedProductAccessories::class,
    UpdateProductVouchers::class,
    UpdateRelatedProductMedia::class,
    UpdateRelatedProductDescription::class,
    UpdateRelatedProductAccessory::class,
    UpdateProductListedMarker::class,
    UpdateCategoryFromOnlyPrice::class,
    UpdateWarranty::class,
    UpdateYoutubeVideo::class,
];

/**
 * The product to be auto mapped.
 *
 * @var Product
 */
public $product;

/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Product $product)
{
    $this->delay = 5;

    $this->product = $product;
}

/**
 * Get the middleware the job should pass through.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function middleware()
{
    return [
        (new WithoutOverlapping($this->product->id))->dontRelease(),
    ];
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();

        foreach ($this->autoMappers as $class) {
            $obj = new $class;

            if (is_callable($obj)) {
                $obj($this->product->refreshWithScopes());
            }
        }

        DB::commit();
    } catch (DuplicateSlug $exception) {
        DB::rollback();

        Log::info($exception->getMessage());

        return;
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        DB::rollback();

        throw $exception;
    }
}
```

Some of the classes above also have auto mappers further.
For instance, UpdateCrossSellAccessories has below:

```
/**
 * Auto map product.
 *
 * @param Product $product
 *
 * @return Product
 */
public static function autoMap(Product $product): Product
{
    $product->accessories()->wherePivot('cross_sell', true)->detach();

    return app(Pipeline::class)
        ->send($product)
        ->through([
            \App\Automation\CrossSellMapping\SearchByManufacturer::class,
            \App\Automation\CrossSellMapping\SearchByProductType::class,
            \App\Automation\CrossSellMapping\SearchByManufacturerAndProductType::class,
            \App\Automation\CrossSellMapping\SearchByManufacturerAndModel::class,
            \App\Automation\CrossSellMapping\SearchByManufacturerModelAndProductType::class,
            \App\Automation\CrossSellMapping\SearchByManufacturerAndAttribute::class,
            \App\Automation\CrossSellMapping\SearchByManufacturerProductTypeAndAttribute::class,
            \App\Automation\CrossSellMapping\SearchByProductTypeAndAttribute::class,
            \App\Automation\CrossSellMapping\SearchByAnyAttribute::class,
            \App\Automation\CrossSellMapping\SearchByExactMatch::class,
        ])->then(function ($product) {
            return $product;
        });
}
```

Comment: Could try to use this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#database-transactions and give it multiple tries. A deadlock pretty much means that two processes are trying to update the same table at the same time

Comment: I see your already using `DB::beginTransaction` but i suggest using the other one cause you can give it multiple tries untill it succeseed

Comment: @HashtagForgotName I understand why it leads to a deadlock, but is it possible to know which queries leads to a lock, how can I debug? I want to update my query or I want to do a check if current row is in lock state or notso I don't get deadlocks in the first place.